# How to increase this Mysql Query performance?

Tags: mysql, database

I wrote following query as per requirement with big tables. 
If i give limit 10 or 1000, it takes same loading time for both.
Please help to increase this query performance.

```
SELECT
    col1,
    col2,
    (SELECT MAX(tcol1) FROM table2 WHERE REPLACE(tcol1,' s',' ')=col1 AND tcol2 = col2) AS max,
    (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table2 WHERE REPLACE(tcol1,' s',' ')=col1 AND tcol2 = col2) AS count
FROM 
    table1
ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 10
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query . In addition, questions about query performance always require CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables as well as the result of the EXPLAIN

Comment: As you are using an `order by`, the query will have to process every row before it applies the limit.  So the limit won't change the performance that much if it's retrieving 1 or 1000 rows as the time is taken before that.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    t1.col1,
    t1.col2,
    A.MAX,
    A.Count
FROM 
    table1 t1
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT MAX(tcol1) AS MAX, 
           COUNT(1) AS COUNT 
        FROM table2 
        GROUP BY tcol1, tcol2
    ) A 
    ON t1.col1=A.col1 
    AND t1.col2 = A.col2
ORDER BY COUNT DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Now this query is working and giving same result which query i ve used already. But this one also taking same loading time. I'm getting following result in explain extended. `Using where; Using join buffer - 13866 rows`